# How to determine if element attribute exists or not using TestCafe?

Tags: testing, css-selectors, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm using TestCafe and would like to determine if the checkbox element is present or not. In the HTML element, if the checkbox is already checked then the attribute `checked` exists otherwise not. How do I determine using TestCafe?

I used the function available in TestCafe - `.hasAttribute('checked')` but the return is `undefined`.

Here is the HTML code when the checkbox is checked:

`<input class="jss1523" tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value checked>`

Here is the HTML code when the checkbox is unchecked:

`<input class="jss1523" tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value>`

How do I solve this using TestCafe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every Dom element which you get with `Selector()` you can check property `checked` - https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html#members-specific-to-element-nodes

For checkboxes and radio inputs it returns Boolean value (`true` - if checked, `otherwise` - false) and for other types of elements return `undefined`